# Как в теле скрипта задать вывод шаблона ejs c элементом массива?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

Пробую динамически добавлять данные в таблицу.
Данные mdata берутся из схемы mongoose.
Возникает ошибка синтаксиса  в следующей строке:
 var obj = `<%- mdata.EcrACQTask[${i}]._id %>`;
На стороне клиента в браузере ругается на индекс, а  точнее на конструкцию ${i}.
Если подставить значение индекса, например `<%- mdata.EcrACQTask[0]._id %>`, то всё корректно работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать?

```
<script  type = "text/javascript">

    var table = document.getElementById("mdTable"); // table
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);  
    var th  = newRow.insertCell(0);
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++){  

        for(var i = 0; i < '<%- mdata.EcrACQTask.length %>'; i++){  
            var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);                          

            var th  = newRow.insertCell(0);  // th
            var td1 = newRow.insertCell(1);  // td
            var td2 = newRow.insertCell(2);  // td 
            var td3 = newRow.insertCell(3);  // td


            var obj = `<%- mdata.EcrACQTask[${i}]._id %>`;
            alert (obj);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

.<%- %> нужен для include... 
используйте <% name %>

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем пришлось переделать с применением шаблонизатора EJS вместо вставки JS. Только я так понял, что шаблонизатор EJS не поддерживает конструкцию "switch case". Или всё-таки я ошибаюсь? У меня с применением "switch case" происходит ошибка компиляции.
Если применить через "if-else", то всё работает.

```html
<% for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {%>
  
   <% for (var i = 0; i < mdata.EcrACQTask.length; i++ ) {%>
  
     <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>                        

        <% if (j == 0) { %>                            

           <td> ecrACQTaskID.<%- mdata.EcrACQTask[i].index %></td>
           <td> <%- mdata.EcrACQTask[i]._id %></td>
           <td> Task id </td>

        <% } else if (j == 1) { %>                            

           <td> ecrACQTaskType.<%- mdata.EcrACQTask[i].index %></td>
           <td> <%- mdata.EcrACQTask[i]._type[0].title %></td>
           <td> Task type </td>

        <% } else if( j == 2) { %>

           <td> ecrACQTaskFirst.<%- mdata.EcrACQTask[i].index %></td>
           <td> <%- mdata.EcrACQTask[i].first %></td>
           <td> First task </td>

        <% } else if(j == 3) { %>

           <td> ecrACQTaskNum.<%- mdata.EcrACQTask[i].index %></td>
           <td> <%- mdata.EcrACQTask[i].num %></td>
           <td> Task priority </td>

        <% } %>        
     
     </tr>

   <% } %>

<% } %>
```